# Chaining sprite sequences in Corona SDK?

Tags: plugins, lua, sprite, coronasdk, chain

So, I was chaining some sprite sequences recently and it took me a long time, considering the actual simplicity of the chain. I noticed, that if one wanted to do some more complex chains, that it would be extremely frustrating and probably not worth the effort.

This is a very simplified case with a sequence changing method of a sprite object, due to multiple image sheets, which works properly. But as soon as you get more complex, you end up with really hard to read code :

```
        function fox:playSeq()
            pcall(function() self:removeEventListener("sprite", self.sequenceChanger) end)
            local counter = 0
            function self.sequenceChanger(event)
                if event.phase == "ended" then
                    counter = counter + 1
                    if counter == 3 then
                        counter = 0
                    end
                    self:setSequence("walking"..(counter + 1))
                    self:play()
                end
            end
            self:addEventListener("sprite", self.sequenceChanger)
            self:play()
        end
```

I was just wondering if anybody here is aware of a plugin (module), that made the process of making a little more complex sprite animations (chaining them) easier.

Thanks for your help!

Greetings, Nils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not use sprite animation so far but maybe this advises will be useful for you.
Try

- use [Spine](http://esotericsoftware.com) (no free, Trial version available, export to Corona). Read more: [Is Spine Essential For Basic Animation](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/53034-is-spine-essential-for-basic-animation/)
- how to make animations in Corona SDK - see video [The Corona SDK - Ep 11 - Animation Sequences](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLjSZiWFgoc) on YouTube
- some useful tips from [Tutorial: Dynamically-optimized sprites](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/10/09/dynamically-optimized-sprite-sheets/)

Comment: Though I'm planning to stay with sprite sheets for now, this seems to be helpful in a way. So thanks! If noone's aware of the kind of plugin, I've talked about, then I'll consider to make the effort and write it myself maybe. :)